# Images in a figure not showing

Tags: graphics, floats

I am trying to insert a figure with multiple images in a dcument. But only a part of an image is showing or only the last image is showing or they even hide the text above.

```
...
The following figures show the B-spline basis functions calculated later on.

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width = 300pt]{../Obrazky/BSpline/bspline_basis_functions_U7_deg0}
\includegraphics[width = 300pt]{../Obrazky/BSpline/bspline_basis_functions_U7_deg1}
\includegraphics[width = 300pt]{../Obrazky/BSpline/bspline_basis_functions_U7_deg2}
\includegraphics[width = 300pt]{../Obrazky/BSpline/bspline_basis_functions_U7_deg3}
\caption{B-spline basis f..}
\label{fig:B-splineBasisF..}
\end{figure}
...
```

But this is what I get:

[image]

Moreover, when the figure "fits" at the same page as the text, it hides part of it:

```
.. is a generalization of the Bézier representation.

For later computation it will be also useful to know that ...

The following figure shows the B-spline basis functions calculated later on.


\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width = 300pt]{../Obrazky/BSpline/bspline_basis_functions_U7_deg0}
\caption{B-spline basis f..}
\label{fig:B-splineBasisF..}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Do you have any idea why could this happen?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you think of adding `\\ ` between successive `\includegraphics`? Can you check the bounding boxes of the graphic files?

Comment: Thanks. Adding ` \ \ `  doesnt change anything.

Comment: And the bounding boxes? It is not uncommon that scientific graphic files have (invisible) white areas, and are larger than what is seems.

Comment: I tried to adjust the bounding boxes but it did not work. So I put `\includegraphics*` instead of `\includegraphics` whichs seems to work so far

Comment: What does the starred version do?

Comment: "_If * is present, then the graphic is ‘clipped’ to the size specified. If * is omitted, then any part of the graphic that is outside the specified ‘bounding box’ will over-print the surrounding text._"

Comment: I see. Never used it, as I always check the bounding boxes first.

Comment: I tried to handle the optimal bounding box using epstool, I tried to modify the bounding box directly in the eps file but there were either no changes or bad changes, so I am happy I found this way at the end..

Comment: Can't you convert it to .pdf format. The excellent  `epspdftk` tool does a very good job at computing a tight bounding box.